# Sign jar with certificate but without private key

Tags: java, jarsigner

I have a basic question about signing a jar file with a provided certificate. I have a certificate(.pem file) that I wish to use to sign a jar. I do not have its private key.

The command that I used till now is: `jarsigner -keystore /working/mystore -storepass <keystore password> -keypass <private key password> -signedjar sbundle.jar bundle.jar test`. Is there a way to sign the jar without the private key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, by definition you need the private key to sign, that's the whole idea. You cannot sign with just the public certificate containing the public key, you can only verify with it.